# When sending second message , first message reaches the user first rather than the actual message in Node js Sockets.io

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I am trying to make a real time chat application with nodeJs and sockets.io . But I am facing a problem what's happening is with me is when am emitting a message using node js sockets

**the message reaches to the other user correctly but When am sending the second message the first message goes first to the receiver then the actual message which I wanted to send to receiver reaches to him .**

Please help me to solve this problem .

Below is my frontend node js code

```
<script>
    var socket = io();

    var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    var btn = document.getElementById('send');
    btn.addEventListener('click', add)


    var Name = prompt('Kindly Enter your name below :- ');
    console.log(Name)

    socket.emit('parsing name', Name)

    function updateScroll() {
        var element = document.getElementById("messages");
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
    }

    function add() {
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div')
        newDiv.className = 'msg-right message';
        newDiv.textContent = input.value;
        messages.appendChild(newDiv);
    }

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (input.value) {
            socket.emit('chat message', input.value);
            socket.emit('parsing name', Name)
            input.value = '';
            updateScroll();
        }
    });


    socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
        var item = document.createElement('div');
        item.className = 'msg-left message'
        item.textContent = msg;
        messages.appendChild(item);


        updateScroll();
    });

    socket.on('joined-log', function(Person) {
        var specialMsg = document.createElement('div');
        specialMsg.className = 'special-msg';
        specialMsg.textContent = 'PERSON name :- ' + Person + " , joined the chat";
        messages.appendChild(specialMsg);

        updateScroll();
    })
</script>
```

And now this is my backend code

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('A user connected')
    socket.on('personName', (Name) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('joined-log', Name)
    })

    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
        socket.on('parsing name', (Name) => {
            socket.broadcast.emit('chat message', Name + ":- " + msg); // Send message to everyone BUT sender
            console.log('Chat Message  ' + Name + ':-  ', msg)
        })
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', (msg) => {
        console.log('User Disconnected')
    });

});


http.listen(80, () => {
    console.log('listening on 80');
});
```

Can anyone tell me how do I send only message at a time and that also the correct one and Please consider the fact I am a total noob with sockets.io

Comment: move `socket.on('parsing name'` to outside of `socket.on('chat message'`

Comment: Thankyou so much from the deepest point of my heart , it solved my problem thankyou so much again